# Does Google update redirect URLs?

Tags: redirect, google-search

I have shortened my URL on my e-commerce store to make them more SEO friendly however some of my original URL are in a good position on Google.

If I redirect my *old* URLs to my new URL will Google automatically update my old URLs to display my new URLs?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the behaviour of a web service, without any relation to programming.

Comment: This question probably does belong on webmasters.stackexchange.com. That said, Google may update the URLs _faster_ if you use permanent redirects, but as long as everything links to your new URLs Google will eventually catch up anyway. (Still, the redirects sound like a good idea no matter what.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you use permanent (301) redirects. That's pretty much the full answer.